# Adding css/js files to the home site in the admin's panel django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to add a simple script to my admin's panel in django. I am following this example from the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions), which works when I do this:

```
    class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        class Media:
            js = ("my_code.js",)

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

`my_code.js` (which lives in `STATICFILES_DIRS`) gets executed when I open the "Article" link in the admin's panel (so this would be the example url: `localhost:8000/admin/news/article/`)

However, I want it to be executed in the home site, as in right after I login to the admin's panel (this would be the url:`localhost:8000/admin/`) .  Where do I have to insert the `class Media` then?

Comment: You should consider customizing the admin template to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to make your custom javascript appear on all admin pages? Then the best thing to do is to [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates) the default admin templatte.

Look in your django installation and find `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html` make a copy of it in `templates/admin` in your project folder. Then simply add the following to the html.

```
<script scr="my_code.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then the js will be available on all admin pages.

Comment: that worked, thanks ! I was hoping there would be an easier solution

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Comment: I'm wondering if this is possible to achieve with overwriting the admin's template instead of copying as explained in here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template As far as I understood it is not

Comment: You do not over write the templats. They will be lost when you upgrade django or when you run your app on a different server

Answer (score 1):

I found another way which is overriding instead of replacing as explained in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template).

If you place the file `base.html` into `templates/admin`:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block footer %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'my_code.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock  %}
```

This will insert the script after the footer in the at `localhost:8000/admin/`.

Here I am "overriding" `the base.html`. But since I am using `.super` (explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)) it adds the script after the footer tag.